# Cannot add new pods to project : Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

Hi fellow overflowers,

I've been pulling my hair for more than a week on this issue now and I can't seem to find anything at all.
I don"t know why or how, but at one point my project stopped accepting more Pods, let me explain. Here is my Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '4.3'
pod 'SVGeocoder', :git => 'https://github.com/kirualex/SVGeocoder.git'
pod 'KALayoutHelper', :git => 'https://github.com/kirualex/KALayoutHelper.git'
pod 'SBJson', '3.1.1'
pod 'AFNetworking', '0.10.1'
pod 'SDWebImage', '2.4'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'iActiveRecord'
```

Everything is working great with it, but here's the trick, as soon as I want to add a new pod (such as Flurry or Crittercism), I get the same kind of error :

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crittercism", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I'm getting very frustrated with this as I'm near the end of this project and I am currently forced to import these libraries by the "dirty old way" ! Any help would be very very much appreciated !

Comment: Have you tried deleting you `Podfile.lock` file and running `pod install` again?

Comment: Yep, no change... Thanks for your idea anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out where the issue was, it was linked to a faulty podspec file from a library I was using (SVGeocoder, see Podfile). The podspec did not pose any problem while making a pod update although the line specifying the libraries was corrupted. I changed :

```
s.framework    = 'CoreLocation, MapKit'
```

to

```
s.framework    = 'CoreLocation', 'MapKit'
```

and everything is now back on track.